# I am trying to round a nested string that has both string and int

Tags: python-3.x

I have tried
newlist= is list i want to round but without the string but i m having troubles putting the string in their right place since its nested list.

```
numerosArredondados = [[round(val, 2) for val in sublst] for sublst in newList]
```

is there a way to get that to work while ignoring the string

```
list=[["str",1.0293,82,394....],["str2",12.32,4.21...],....]
```

end result

```
 roundedlist=[["str",1.,82,3....],["str2",12.3,4.2...],....]
```

Comment: `[[round(val, 2) if isinstance(val, (int, float)) else val for val in sublst] for sublst in newList]`

Answer (score 0):

```
[[round(val, 2) if isinstance(val, (int, float)) else val for val in sublst] for sublst in newList]
```

works many thanks to @Tomerikoo